# If an effect destroys multiple creatures, in what order are they destroyed?

Tags: keyforge

If I use a card like Gateway to Dis to destroy multiple creatures, how do we decide in which order they are destroyed, what effects can be applied, and in what order they land in the discard pile?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If an effect destroys multiple creatures, they are destroyed simultaneously, so any effects on the creatures being destroyed are not eligible to be applied on the other creatures (e.g. Tolas would not gain you anyone any aember, since it is also destroyed). For an effect to be applied, it needs to still be in play after the destruction is finished. The cards also all hit the discard pile at the same time, but the active player does get to choose the order in which they go in.
[Reference video.](https://youtu.be/ESETHb99U40?t=768)
[image]